# Google Sheets ladder linked with Google Drive folder

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google, google-drive-shared-folder

For a project at school, I have around 340 pages (170 spreads) labeled with the contents of the page/spread in the cell in a Google Sheet. I also have a Drive where every spread has a folder (ie 002-003, 004-005). I hyperlinked the folders on the page numbers in the ladder, but was wondering if there is a simpler way to link 170+ folders into the Sheet? If not I could take an hour or so to link it but was wondering if there was a way to save some time.